# How can I describe Lie bracket for formal product of elements of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let L be a Lie algebra with basis $B=\{x_1,...,x_{10}\}$, Is there any property to describe the following lie bracket: for example how I can decompose $[x_1 x_2 x_3 , x_5]=$? Here $x_1  x_2 x_3$ is the formal product of the elements of Lie algebra.

Comment: What is a formal product? The commutator in the universal enveloping algebra?

Comment: @ darij grinberg, yes , universal enveloping algebra is defined as the span of formal products of elements of Lie algebra.

Comment: As in @darijgrinberg's comment, there is some danger in attempting to describe the universal enveloping algebra as "formal products". Sure, there's the Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem, but that oughtn't be relevant too often. Use the mapping-property characterization.

Answer (score 2):

If the Lie algebra derive from an associative Algebra, with the definition
$$
[u,v]=uv-vu,
$$
then you can easily prove that
$$
[uv,w]=u[v,w]+[u,w]v.
$$
For a situation like this:
$$
[x_1^ex_2^fx_3^g,x_5]
$$
with $e$, $f$, $g$ positive integers, you should have
\begin{align}
[x_1^ex_2^fx_3^g,x_5]&=\sum_{h=0}^{e-1} x_1^h           [x_1,x_5]x_1^{e-h-1}x_2^fx_3^g\\
                     &+\sum_{h=1}^{f-1} x_1^e x_2^h     [x_2,x_5]x_2^{f-h-1}x_3^g\\
                     &+\sum_{h=1}^{g-1} x_1^e x_2^fx_3^h[x_3,x_5]x_3^{g-h-1}
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for your answer, if we consider x_1 and x_2 and x_3 with powers, like this: x_1^(e ) x_2^f  x_3^g then how is the result of Lie bracket?